# Что означает последовательность символов между двумя '@' в make синтаксисе

Tags: makefile

```
CC = @CC@
CFLAGS = @CFLAGS@
LIBS = @LIBUNP@ @LIBS@
LIBS_XTI = @LIBUNPXTI@ @LIBUNP@ @LIBS_XTI@
RANLIB = @RANLIB@ ## Заголовок ##
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в синтаксисе программ, понимаемом интерпретатором *make*, эти символы не имеют никакого специального значения.

---

приведённый же вами фрагмент весьма похож на «заготовку» для создания такой программы — файл с именем `Makefile.in` (обратите внимание на суффикс `.in`), который [преобразуется скриптом `configure`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.60/html_node/Makefile-Substitutions.html) (из набора программных средств [gnu/autotools](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotools)) в полноценную программу, понимаемую интерпретатором *make* (в файл с именем `Makefile`, уже без всяких суффиксов).

при этом встречаемые шаблоны `@имя-переменной@` скрипт `configure` заменяет на значения соответствующих переменных (которые либо вписаны в нём напрямую, либо вычисляются в процессе работы скрипта).